# Decoding url $_GET variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I searched a bit, but still looking for a good solution.

I'm getting 'id' from my database then encode it by md5 hashing function before pass it through URL. In edit page I can't check the 'id'(which i get form URL)  with my database , because the 'id' is md5 encoded, but in database there is int value. I found that md5 cannot be decrypted. So how can i get back my id? Or is there any other way to do it securely?

This is how I'm passing data through url:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo md5($row['id']);?>">Edit</a>
```

In edit page I'm getting the 'id' like this:

```
c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

Comment: You waste your time, why you encrypt and decrypt it to only get the ID ? I recommend you to use `hexdec` and `dechex` if you want hexadecimal result. Hacker still knows your ID anyway. So this is useless

Comment: Let's start at square 0: *why* "encrypt" ids in the first place?!

Comment: @deceze there's no need an encryption here

Comment: There's no point in encrypting a `GET` parameter.

Comment: Why I need to encode GET parameter: I'm Making a registration page for a event. It has no login system. After registration each participant will get a link by email (after manual confirmation), where they can find importent info which is need to join the event. If I don't encode the id then any user can access other user info easily by trying random 'id'. As there is no login system and Can't use $_SESSION, I think the best way is encode the 'id' to prevent users to access random data.

I'm very new to programing and learning, I endup here with this soliution.

Comment: @AmirulIslam Instead of using a simple encoding scheme, use truly random, long ids instead! As I noted below, anyone who really wants to will recognize a base64 encoded value and will access random users accounts anyway. Look into using UUIDs instead!

Comment: @deceze Thanks a lot. Although base64 encode the value but I found that base64 is not so useful, if anyone try a little he/she can easily access other users data. 

Before post this question I searched by google and also found some link about UUID, but don't understand much. Can you please suggest some refference site where I can learn about UUID?

Thansk a lot for your great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, for the basic way, there's no point in encrypting the `$_GET` parameter, which is visible. Either find your own encryption way, or use sessions or cookies.

One easy thing I would suggest is:

- Using `POST` instead of `GET`.
- A less secure way is `base64_*` functions. See below.

You can use [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to do this:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id'];?>">Edit</a>
```

And in the file:

```
base64_decode($_GET["id"])
```

Will fetch you the ID.

Comment: Tried base64_encrypt() but the output is "Fatal error: Call to undefined function base64_encrypt()"

Comment: @AmirulIslam there is no function in php called base64_encrypt(), that should be base64_encode().

Comment: MD5 can cause collision. You should not use MD5 as the encryptor. Just give OP the best workaround. Your `base64_encode` is enough

Comment: @Michael Yes yes, the Department of Justice should certainly get on MD5's case...! *(I think you mean "collision".) ;-P*

Comment: @deceze :p :p the Department of Justice :v

Comment: @Praveen So how is this any more "secure"?! I'm assuming "security" is the goal here... Any "hacker" will readily spot Base64 encoded data, decode it, see that it's an integer, and simply try all sorts of Base64 encoded integers themselves. What does this Base64 encoding dance gain here?

Comment: @deceze The question has some flaws. We cannot answer everything. I understand that there should be Secure Algo... But this is just a beginning. I am a security expert too, and I can give a better solution than this. **But that's not our job, is it?** The OP has to research well.

Comment: If the OP is on the entirely wrong track, then don't help them along, **tell them they're on the wrong track!**

Comment: I think you all,, could keep it secure by playing at SESSION and COOKIE ... URL Params is dangerous, because anyone can see it

Comment: @MichaelAntonio Even `form` we can do. See we are wasting time, while the OP is sitting idle. Stop chatting guys. Let's wait till that OP speaks up.

Comment: I am the down voter, I told you what I disagree with, no need to clutter up your answer with such meta topics.

Comment: Interesting discussion :p

Comment: @deceze So what I should make my answer for you to remove the downvote?

Comment: Nice, I get downvotes for helping some ass who cannot even do an initial research. Wow... Long live these people!

Comment: I am moving on to get my hands on other real challenging and good questions. Thanks @deceze. Tell me one thing to remove your downvote, so that I can make it better. That's what I meant it.

Comment: What more can I say? Tell the OP that encryption is likely pretty darn pointless. Period.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Neel Ion and @Praven Kumar. It's now working fine, as I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm Making a registration page for a event. It has no login system. After registration each participant will get a link by email (after manual confirmation), where they can find importent info which is need to join the event. If I don't encode the id then any user can access other user info easily by trying random 'id'.

What you want for this then is an *unguessable random id*. Any scheme where you simply *encode* your primary database id using MD5 or Base64 is neither *unguessable* nor *random*, it just looks that way on first glance. But both MD5 and Base64 strings are somewhat recognisable due to their length and/or format, so anyone catching wind of the fact that you merely encode a number this way will gladly do the same and crawl all your links.

No, you must create a truly ***random*** id. An id which is not based on anything else (like a simple integer counter), but is purely random nonsense. Only someone who *has been told* this random value can know it, you cannot arrive at this random value simply by guessing. To do this the random value needs to be large enough to make guessing unviable (e.g., you can't make a few billion guesses in a reasonable amount of time).

[UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid) are perfect for this, [here's the "official" PHP package](https://pecl.php.net/package/uuid) for it, but you can find others as well. Alternatively, get a long string of [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) and [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex) or [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) it.